# "set -o vi" how to get the yank in the clipboard

Tags: linux, shell, vim

My goal is to yank a line in the shell (for example with yy) into the system clipboard and then paste it somewhere else (for example in the internet browser). How can I accomplish that?

Comment: vi doesn't know about the GUI's clipboard, but the terminal emulator you run it in does.  Use the terminal emulator to highlight the line and copy it into the clipboard.

Comment: AFAIK, bash's vi mode deals only with what is currently at the prompt. Do you want to yank what's currently at the prompt or some previous text from a previous command?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get the end result you want (pasting code from shell to internet broswer) is to:

- Select the text with your mouse cursor
- `Ctrl+Shift+C` to copy
- `Ctrl+V` to paste outside of terminal
- `Ctrl+Shift+V` to paste into a terminal prompt

Comment: Note this is not universal - some terminals will support it, others use different hot-keys, and yet others won't do it at all, but will allow you to select/copy/paste with mouse actions. Better answer is to check the documentation for the terminal emulator you are using...

Answer (score -1):

Your vim need have *+xterm_clipboard* flag, you can check this with `vim --version | grep +xterm_clipboard`. If your vim isn't compiled with this flag, you can compile it yourself or try to install *gvim* (usually it comes with this flag).

For access to the system clipboard you have to type those sequences:

- **Copy** (a word): `"*yw`
- **Paste**: `"*p`

See: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard

Comment: He's not trying to copy & paste from vim, but from bash, using its vi key-bindings.